# Add php code after product price on shop and archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

[Link attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRG4C.jpg)

I am trying to add code php  after price (not on single product pages) but on sshop pages and archive page (As image).

**The php code I want to insert is:**

```
<?php the_author_meta( 'phone' ); ?>
```

Looking forward to the help of experts. Sincerely thank !

Comment: This hook: `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` as shown here: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this added to your functions.php:

Modify to your needs.

```
function woocommerce_after_cat_price() {
    echo the_author_meta( 'phone' );
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_after_cat_price', 10, 0);
```